# What is this code doing and how can I write it more simply?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, metaprogramming

```
[:initial_amount, :rate_increase_amount].each do |method|
  define_method method do
    self["#{method}_in_cents".to_sym].to_f/100 if self["#{method}_in_cents".to_sym]
  end

  define_method "#{method}=" do |_value|
    self["#{method}_in_cents".to_sym] = _value.to_f * 100
  end
end
```

It's giving the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `initial_amount_in_cents' for #&lt;ViolationType:0x6220a88>
```

I tried to re-write it as:

```
def initial_amount_in_cents
  initial_amount_in_cents.to_f/100 if initial_amount_in_cents
end

def rate_increase_amount_in_cents
  rate_increase_amount_in_cents.to_f/100 if rate_increase_amount_in_cents
end

def initial_amount= (value)
  initial_amount_in_cents = value.to_f * 100
end

def rate_increase_amount= (value)
  rate_increase_amount_in_cents = value.to_f * 100
end
```

But it gave me this error instead:

```
ERROR SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

Comment: Instead of asking why incorrect code isn't working, can you explain what it is you would like it to do?  `Stack level too deep` is because the method is calling itself repeatedly without any way of breaking out.

Comment: OMG isn't that infinite recursion obvious?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky No, because I don't know about Ruby reflection. I even tried something else, which didn't work. See updated edit.

Comment: Rejection isn't relevant here, you have a method that calls itself. While Boris could use an attitude adjustment, he's correct, and it *is* pretty obvious. Let's turn it on its head: why *don't* you see the recursion? In any case, your manual methods aren't equivalent-perhaps you meant to use an instance variable instead of a recursive call?

Answer (score 2):

### Problems

You have several, including:

1. Overly "clever" code. Don't do things like this without a good reason.
2. Recursive calls. You might consider using [defined?](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F) or something to avoid this.
3. An example that's missing a lot of context.

Being DRY doesn't mean being obscure. If the code doesn't make sense to you the way it's written, refactor it for clarity.

### What It's Probably Trying to Do

The code is apparently trying to dynamically define an `_in_cents` method for related methods that accept a float. You'd have to ask the author why he (or she) wrote it that way, but that's what it's for, whether or not it currently works for you.

### Possible Solution

With all that said, this may help. Assuming you have defined attributes in your model for `initial_amount` and `rate_increase_amount` then you should be able to simplify the call to [Module#define_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method). For example:

```
class YourRailsModel
  %i[initial_amount rate_increase_amount].each do |method|
    # You don't have a real Rails model here, so we create accessors to simulate
    # model attributes.
    attr_accessor method

    define_method "#{method}_in_cents" do
      Integer(Float send(method) * 100)
    end
  end
end

model = YourRailsModel.new
model.initial_amount = 0.97
# => 0.97

model.initial_amount_in_cents
# => 97
```

Comment: Note that `%i` is a Ruby 2.0-ism. Specify the actual symbols in a comma-separated array if that literal constructor doesn't work for you.